# Virtualbox Ubuntu 16.04 guest doesn't work with video memory above 50MB

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, video

I'm trying to set up a Virtualbox using Ubuntu 16.04 as guest (and host as well, the machine is an Alienware 17R3).

However, the video does not seems to work. I did a fresh install and did install the guest additions.

Finally, I reduced the problem that if I set the video memory to 50MB and disable the 3D acceleration, the video start playing. The play is a little chopy and does not flow well, but it plays.

How can I increase the memory of the video card and have the machine play videos?

Let me know if you need some logs.

Host specs:

- RAM: 16 GB

Guest specs:

- RAM: 10000 MB

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate to the guest OS? How much RAM in the host? Cheers, Al

Comment: What are you using to play the video? Unfortunately, VB 3D acceleration tends to conflict with 3D acceleration in the VM. Why are you watching videos under Virtualbox Ubuntu anyway?

Comment: I have around 10GB for the guest, and I disabled the 3D and still got errors on the video. I notice the error because the general video is shown like in blocks when it is rendered (normal window, not video). Then I noticed that video wasn't playing. So i figured that the problem may be the graphics card or memory on the guest.